# ffprobe returning video stream data twice

Tags: ffmpeg, ffprobe

I'm trying to return specific values from ffprobe:

`ffprobe -v error -select_streams V:0 -show_entries stream=index,width,height,sample_aspect_ratio,display_aspect_ratio:format=duration  -of default=noprint_wrappers=1:nokey=1 test.MTS`

The stream values in the output are repeated:

```
0
1920
1080
1:1
16:9
0
1920
1080
1:1
16:9
116.640000
```

The format value is not repeated.
If I strip the printer values to see what's going on:

`ffprobe -v error -select_streams V:0 -show_entries stream=index,width,height,sample_aspect_ratio,display_aspect_ratio:format=duration  test.MTS`

I see a section called [PROGRAM] with stream 0 repeated within it:

```
[PROGRAM]
[STREAM]
index=0
width=1920
height=1080
sample_aspect_ratio=1:1
display_aspect_ratio=16:9
[/STREAM]
[/PROGRAM]
[STREAM]
index=0
width=1920
height=1080
sample_aspect_ratio=1:1
display_aspect_ratio=16:9
[/STREAM]
[FORMAT]
duration=116.640000
[/FORMAT]
```

Can someone please help me to return only the video stream 0 values once?

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a general help site, but is only for questions specifically about programming. Try [su] next time for `ff*` cli usage questions.

Comment: @LordNeckbeard while this is entirely true, ffmpeg and friends are arguably "software tools commonly used by programmers" because video encoding is a task commonly automated or scripted, and this tool is ubiquitous in the domain.

Comment: @SirDarius Using that logic, any cli tool usage question can then be considered on-topic.

Comment: I'm using vb to manipulate videos via ffprobe and ffmpeg. I didn't want to muddy the question with unnecessary details so I condensed my question to the essence of the problem. I posted here because I thought other programmers would have used ffprobe in this way to return values to their code. As an aside, I think the answer will be useful to programmers.

Answer (score 1):

The regular `stream` doesn't have a unique section name. You can however select just the program streams using `-show_entries program_stream` or just discard the extra information. See `ffprobe -sections`

Comment: `-show_entries program_stream=index,width,height,sample_aspect_ratio,display_aspect_ratio:format=duration` I don't know about the programs, didn't look in detail. I would discard the extra data. It can output JSON or XML if it helps you.

Comment: thank you, I'm working through it step by step right now.

Comment: this: 
`ffprobe -v error -select_streams V:0 -show_entries program_stream=index,width,height,sample_aspect_ratio,display_aspect_ratio:format=duration -of default=noprint_wrappers=1:nokey=1 test.mts` gives me the result I need :-) My only concern - if anyone knows - is that I might come across a video that does not have a stream within a program.

Comment: Yes, as I feared; most of the videos I pointed this at returned nothing for a program_stream